# Vmware Esxi Vcenter 6.7 Fault tolerance for VM is greyed out

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, fault-tolerance

I'm very new to VMWARE. I'm trying to do fault tolerance for one of my VMS on Vcenter 6.7 but the Fault tolerance tab is greyed out for some reason. I have to 2 esxi servers in my vcenter and both are within the same cluster that has HA and DRS turned on. I have enabled fault tolerance logging on the Vmotion kernel for both esxi1 and 2. Can anyone help please, how to solve this?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: FT has quite strict requirements for the virtual hardware. Make sure your VM matches them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah I have checked that against the hardware requirement and it qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

Check the easy stuff first, on VM configuration:

- Do you have any cd drive or iso connected?
- Passthrough NICs?
- usb devices?
- Are more vCPUs enabled on VM that the limit allowed by your vSphere license?

Since you've enabled fault tolerance logging on the vMotion kernel, I suppose you have enabled and tested vMotion. Do this please if you haven't.

What is your vSphere edition, it should be at least standard, essentials are not supported.

---

[Fault Tolerance Requirements, Limits, and Licensing, vSphere 6.7](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.avail.doc/GUID-57929CF0-DA9B-407A-BF2E-E7B72708D825.html)
Just in case you haven't read it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'm using the evaluation vCenter version 6.7 . I have removed the CD and USB. only 1 vCPU for this VM. I can migrate the VMs without a problem so I think the vMotion is working.

Comment: Probably it's due to evaluation. On the other hand, ff I recall well, during the evaluation period all features all enabled, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I read all features are open within the evaluation period. I have tried even creating a new VMkernel with FT enabled, connected to the vMotion vswitch, but to no avail. Even restarted both ESXI servers just to make sure. I can not tell what's causing this at all.

Comment: Evaluation allows FT for sure. What shared storage do you have?